# Will model.predict update a GRU layer states correctly?

Tags: python, tensorflow, input, recurrent-neural-network, training-data

This is my first question, suggestions are appreciated!

### Background

I built a model similar to this one.
[image: my model]

I am using `model.predict(inputs)` to make predictions and I built my custom functions and process to make it learn. It seems to work and when it predicts all seems good.

Some days ago, I watched this video:
https://youtu.be/8HyCNIVRbSU?t=284
(It starts in the part that generated my question) And I copied the image that caught my attention:
[image: LSTM]
It says that each input is inserted sequentially on each cell, and each cell will provide more information to the next in that order.

I began to wonder if my implementation is correct and I will give you all the details that might be useful.

### Details

1. I **am** using `stateful=True` for both GRU layers.
2. The input at `model.predict(inputs)` is defined like `inputs = [np.array(arr).reshape(1, 1, 6), np.array(arr2).reshape(1, 1, 4)]`.
3. I have a CSV with the values of the first part of the input, but for the other values, I create them on the fly. That is why I used `model.predict`. Because of this, if there is another way to be able to send both the static and "dynamic data", I would be happy to do it.
4. The only way that I am interacting with the model after loading it is by asking to predict the values, and by updating its weights (and resetting states when I input a new sequence).

Now, with all this information, the question would be:

- **Is model. predict updating all the cell states correctly and using the GRU layer to its full capacity?**
- **Or is it just sending the data to the first cell always?**

Comment: GRU (and other RNNs) takes the first item from your sequence, recalculates its state, takes the second item, recalculates its state and so on

Comment: Even though I am using the `predict` method? That is the thing that worries me. Thank you for your help!

Comment: forward pass for `predict()` is the same as for `fit()`

Comment: Great! Would you mind if you upload an answer so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a course of forward pass (either `predict()` or `fit()`) GRU (and other RNNs) takes the first item from your sequence, recalculates its state, takes the second item, recalculates its state and so on.